# Very simple Mailchimp API request example

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am newbie in Mailchimp API. So, I'd like to export my customers email from CRM to Mailchimp. It requires HTTP request (Json available).

What should I use for HTTP request? I need very simple example.

Comment: does MailChimp have any user documentation you can look at? those would probably include some examples.

Comment: Sure, but I don't understand it exactly.

Comment: perhaps look through other mailchimp-related questions on StackOverflow and see if there are similar questions. you haven't even mentioned what technology you plan to use to do this, so it's hard to point you in the right direction other than the MailChimp documentation which has links to help for various languages and technologies. good luck!